# PHP install mailparser extension

Tags: php, php-extension, email-parsing

I want to install mailparser extension. 
I downloaded php_malparse.dll ( put it to php/ext folder). 
Also added : `extension=php_mailparse.dll`  to php.ini

But it doesn't work, and php_info() doesn't show it too.

In logs I get:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\xampp\php\ext\php_mailparse.dll' - %1 \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd‌​\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd‌​\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf‌​\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef‌​\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd‌​\xef\xbf\xbd Win32.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

I need help, how can I solve this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: In logs I get : PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_mailparse.dll' - %1 \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd Win32.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to say what's going on here. Typically the message `Unable to load dynamic library` means the library (in this case on Windows the `.dll` file) is not correctly formatted and the OS was unable to map it into memory *or* PHP was not able to use it.

Some possible reasons include:

- The extension was not compiled for the same architecture as the target PHP build (e.g. the PHP is `x86-64` but the library is `x86`)
- The extension was not compiled using the same runtime version; PHP is pretty strict about this (e.g. PHP5 is built with `vc11` on Windows, PHP7 is built with `vc14`, ETC.)
- The extension was not compiled against the same version of the PHP API or extension API used by your PHP build; typically PHP will show a more-detailed error message when this is the case (it's strange that your error message contains a bunch of non-printing characters though...)

To double-check all this, view a dump of `phpinfo()` to see what kind of PHP you have. Look for the PHP API and extension versions as well as the system architecture and whether thread safety is enabled. Then return to where you downloaded the `php_mailparse.dll` extension library and make sure the extension aligns with your PHP build. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php#install.pecl.windows.which) are some official instructions for this process for Windows PHP extensions.

I found official builds of this module [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mailparse/). There are a lot of different choices to pick from. Pay attention to `ts` (i.e. Thread-safe) vs `nts` (i.e. Non-thread-safe), `x86` vs `x64` (i.e. the architecture) and `vc11` vs `vc14` (i.e. the runtime version). You may have to experiment until you find one that works for your PHP build.

It might also be worth checking out [the official install instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/mailparse.installation.php) for the `mailparse` extension. Note especially that the `mbstring` module has to be loaded first for it to work.